# Strange Boolean Reaction

Tags: php, string, return

```
$alerter2="false";
for ( $counter = 0; $counter <= count($filter); $counter++) {
    $questionsubmitted=strtolower($_POST[question]);
    $currentcheck =$filter[$counter];
    $foundvalue=stripos((string)$questionsubmitted,(string)$currentcheck);
    echo $foundvalue;
    if ($foundvalue==0) {
        $alerter2="true";
    } else { }
}

if (!($alerter2=="true")) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (Name, Email, Question)
        VALUES
        ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[question]')";
} else {
    echo "Please only post appropriate questions";
}
```

For some reason, whenever I run this, stripos returns 0 every time for every iteration. It's supposed to be a filter, and using echo I found that stripos is 0 every time that it appears. However, when I use 0 in the if, it returns true for even those that don't have the word in them.

Where should I use mysql_real_escape_string? After the query? Note, I am making this a piece of code where I want user input to be saved to a database.

Comment: use `mysql_escape_real_string();`  on `$_POST` variables within your `$sql` would be another thing to do

Comment: Using strings to represent "true" and "false". Really??

Comment: *WHO* is teaching this shitty approach? Why are so many people writing code that's vulnerable to SQL Injection, when simple fixes have been available for _over a decade_!?!?!??!

Comment: Indeed. Plus add a die(mysql_error()); OR/AND a error_log() to see better your SQL errors and trace them

Comment: @TimeCoder: Fix your question's title please. "Why isn't this working" is _not_ acceptable as a descriptive title.

Comment: @CoBaLt, it appears further down in the code.

Answer (score 2):

[stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) return false if the value is not found, or 0 if it is the first character. Problem is, php automatically cast boolean to the 0 integer or the 0 integer to false. So I think a cast is happening here and thus the condition don't do what you want.

You can use `===` to also check the type of the variable :

```
if ($foundvalue === 0) {
    $alerter2="true";
}
```

There's more details about this problem in the linked documentation for `stripos`.

You should also remove the empty `else` clause for a cleaner code and use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to sanitize the values before putting them in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
if ($foundvalue==0)
```

to

```
if ($foundvalue===0) // three equals signs
```

or something equivalent, depending on your logic (I didn't quite understand what's going on).

But as everyone says, **THIS CODE IS OPEN TO SQL INJECTION ATTACKS** (among other problems).

Answer (score 0):

Also,

```
$questionsubmitted=strtolower($_POST[question]);
```

should probably be:

```
$questionsubmitted=strtolower($_POST['question']);
```

Comment: Yeah, this does indeed work, but you get a PHP Notice in you Log files each time you do it this way. `question` (without apostrophs) is treated as constant expression (i.e. previously defined by `define('question', 'somevalue')`, although constants should be written in UPPERCASE) first, which in your case isn't.